# Proof by induction of inadequacy of a propositional connective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have the following truth table of a newly defined logical operator and have to prove its functional incompleteness via structural induction.

My idea is that that you cannot express the always true formula $\top$ in terms of this operator.
I just don't know how to go about the proof.

Here is the truth table of the new 3-input Operator:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 X & Y & Z & <X,Y,Z> \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1& 0 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: How about: for any expression in $n$ variables that you can build with the operator, its evaluation at $(0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ is 0?

Comment: thank you for your reply , how does this prove its inadequacy though ?

Comment: You probably already know this, but just in case: <$X,Y,Z$> $\equiv (Y \land Z)\lor X$. I hope  this helps.

Comment: Johoey: The comment by @DanilSchepler means that you can't implement $\neg X$ using only this operator.

Answer (score 1):

We can use structural induction to give a careful proof that any term we can build using only the function symbol $<-,-,->$ and the variable symbol $x$ represents either the identity function or the constant $0$ function.

**Base case $x$**: Upon substituting $1$ for $x$, we get $1$. Upon substituting $0$, we get $0$. Therefore $x$ represents the identity function.

**Inductive case**: Consider a term $f(x)$ form $<A(x),B(x),C(x)>$, where we know by inductive assumption that each of $A(x)$, $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ represents either the identity function or the constant 0 function.

We perform a case analysis, tabulating each of these eight possibilities:

```
A(x) | B(x) | C(x) | x | f(x)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 x   |  x   |  x   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 x   |  x   |  0   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 x   |  0   |  x   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 x   |  0   |  0   | 1 |  1
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (identity)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 0   |  x   |  x   | 1 |  1
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (identity)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 0   |  x   |  0   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 0   |  0   |  x   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
-----|------|------|---|-----
 0   |  0   |  0   | 1 |  0
     |      |      | 0 |  0   (const. 0)
```

We see that in each of these cases, $<A(x),B(x),C(x)>$ represents either the identity function or the constant $0$ function. By the principle of structural induction, any term built using only the function symbol $<-,-,->$ and the variable symbol $x$ represents either the identity function or the constant $0$ function.

Consequently, we cannot express negation or the constant $1$ function using only $<-,-,->$, and so the set $\{ <-,-,-> \}$ is not functionally complete.

Answer (score 0):

$<X,Y,Z>$ or not-$<X,Y,Z>$
has a truth table of all 1's.